# Codeigniter system/language application/language whats the difference?

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

Hey,
in CodeIgniter i have language folder inside my system and inside my application folder...
when im trying to load a language file he trys to load vom the system/language folder

whats the matter of the application/language folder?

my first try was to put the stuff in there and not in the system folder.. this would make more sense in my eyes!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

`If the directory does not exist or the specified language is not located there CI will instead look in your global system/language folder.`

File/folder structure is very important~

So your `english language` file must be called (eg) error_Lang.php **inside** `application/language/english`

Call it like so:

`$this->lang->load('file', 'language');`

I'd read up the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html), has everything you need

Comment: ah ok... i just had a little typing mistake thats why he didnt found the language file in my application folder >_< thanks anyway for the answer :)